# How to make root directory subfolders available through nginx?

Tags: nginx, debian, nginx-config

I've setup **nginx 1.14.2** on my remote server running **Debian 10.6**.
My test site **index.html** located in `/var/www/my-site/` is thus far broadcast well by nginx, when it only has to provide the HTML source code!
However, external CSS or image files fail to be loaded, it seems. The files are located in `/var/www/my-site/css` and `/var/www/my-site/images` respectively.

Here's my **nginx.conf** from `/etc/nginx`, which I only lightly modified by adding a buffer policy, protection against click jacking, and removing older SSL formats:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Buffer Policy
        ##
        client_body_buffer_size 1K;
        client_header_buffer_size 1k;
        client_max_body_size 1k;
        large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;

        ##
        # Avoid Clickjacking Attacks
        ##
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        
        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

And here's my custom **my-site.net** config from `/etc/nginx/sites-available`, which was initialized from the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
# Custom my-site.net configuration
#
server {

        root /var/www/my-site.net;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name my-site.net www.my-site.net;


        ##
        # Deny Automated User Agents
        ##
        if ($http_user_agent ~* LWP::Simple|BBBike|wget) {
                return 403;
        }

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # Get rid of unwanted HTTP methods
                limit_except GET HEAD POST { deny all; }
        }

        ##
        # Stop deep or hot linking
        ##
        location /images/ {
                valid_referers none blocked www.my-site.net my-site.net;
                if ($invalid_referer) {
                        return 403;
                }
        }
        
        ##
        # Certbot Let's Encrypt! SSL
        ##
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-site.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-site.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


server {
    if ($host = www.my-site.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = my-site.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = www.my-site.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = my-site.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name my-site.net my-site.net;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

I've for instance tried to add the lines below to my server block. However, I always get a config error when I try to reload nginx.

```
location \images\ {
    root /var/www/my-site;
}
```

I don't get it! I do have to make subdirectories of the root directory available like this don't I? Or am I getting something totally wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [so], a programmer's forum. Your question seems to be unrelated to programming, so you probably should ask on [sf].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody was able to reply to me, here's how I finally got it working.

My ***FIRST ISSUE*** was with **permissions** and **file ownership**:

`/var/www` was owned by the `root` user and group, as were all its subdirectories and files. nginx thus wasn't able to read any file - even if configured right -, except weirdly my **index.html** from `/var/www/my-site` (which I don't quite understand as of now).

To remedy this, I first changed the owner and group of `/var/www/my-site` and all its subdirectories and files to `www-data`, instead of `root`. `www-data` seems to be the *default user*, defined by nginx. It should be specified at the top of the **nginx.conf** from `/etc/nginx` as `user www-data`.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/my-site
```

After that I also set the SetGID permission flags `s` for the `www-data` group and the `/var/www/my-site` directory and its subdirectories (not the files though).

```
sudo chmod g+s /var/www/my-site /var/www/my-site/images /var/www/my-site/css
```

This means that all future files, created in `/var/www/my-site` and its subdirectories will get the group ownership applied to them (not any new subdirectories though).

Now, I still needed to allow the new group to write to `/var/www/my-site` and its subdirectories with the appropriate permissions (i.e. `rwxrwxrx` = 775):

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/my-site
```

Lastly, I added myself - the non-`root` user - to the `www-data` group, in order to be able to upload (or write) files with for instance SFTP.

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data [my username]
```

`a` means "append", and `-G www-data` "to the existing group `www-data`".

My ***SECOND ISSUE*** was in the **my-site.net** config from `/etc/nginx/sites-available`, which was initially copied from `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`.

Turns out that in my case, I only needed to specify the relevant subdirectories of `/var/www/my-site`, which is the nginx root (cf. `server {...}` block), as `location`s.

I already had `/var/www/my-site/images` set up with this snippet that is meant to prevent hot or deep linking of images:

```
location /images/ {
    valid_referers none blocked www.my-site.net my-site.net;
    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return 403;
    }
}
```

All that remained was to specify another location for `/var/www/my-site/css`:

```
location /css/ {

}
```

Finally, I saved the config and reloaded nginx and everything worked!